# context.log_url as href in airflow not working

Tags: airflow, href, airflow-api

I do not want to use Slack. I 'm just using custom notification(`on_failure_callback`) function in `args` for my mailing function. I have used

```
def task_my_alert(context):
    task_id=context['task'].task_id
    dag_run = context.get('dag_run')
    log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url
    default_html_content = (
             'Log: <a href={log_url}>Link</a><br>'
             'Getback:<a href={MY_AIRFLOW_IP_ADDRESS}>CLICK FOR BACK</a><br>'

        )
sub=f"dag has errors"
send_email(to='my@email.com', subject=sub ,  html_content=default_html_content)
```

But the link`[a href]` is not working for me in my email. ie: I am not getting link in my email. What changes has to be made?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the MIME type to `text/html`.